# Custom title attribute for WordPress stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, stylesheet

How can I add title attribute for my own custom stylesheet in wordpress within functions.php file? I find something like that
`

```
   global $wp_styles;
   $wp_styles->add('example-alt', '/themes/example/example-alt.css');
   $wp_styles->add_data('example-alt', 'title', 'Example Alternate Stylesheet');
   $wp_styles->add_data('example-alt', 'alt', TRUE);
   $wp_styles->enqueue(array('example-alt'));
```

`
but I don't know how can i use it within functions.php file or anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have understood your question. You want to add a CSS Stylesheet to your blog or an attribute to the title?

If you want to add a CSS Stylesheet within functions.php, you have to enqueue it like this:

If your CSS stylesheet is named "my-style.css", place it on a folderl called "css" withing the folder of your theme, and then write that on functions.php:

```
function your_theme_name_scripts() {

    // For Styles: 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri(), '/css/my-style.css' );

    // For Scripts:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri(), '/js/my-script.js' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Your find more info about enqueueing styles here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

If you want to add any attribute to the title, you have two options: creating a filter on functions.php, or directly modifying the wp_title() function on header.php. The second options is the best one. 
You find more info about the title here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title